# req.query undefined in Nuxt Express Middleware get request

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

Not a pro with things like server middleware, but stuck without much clues.

In a vue component I am retrieving data with axios with this:

```
  axios
    .get('/api/getDailyFeedback', {
      params: {
        start: '2018-05-01'
      }
    })
```

Which goes to the express (version 4.16.2) server middleware setup in Nuxt. I have gotten normal get and post requests to work fine but the problem is when I want to pass in a parameter into a get request like the below:

```
router.get('/getDailyFeedback', (req, res) => {
   console.log('Query:', req.query.start);
   //do stuff
});
```

What little experience I had with Express 4, it took me a little bit of time to realise why parameters passed in the body of a post request were undefined, but it was because I needed to add body-parser.json() to my nuxt config since they removed that from the main express package. Similarly I thought I needed bodyParse.urlencoded but that has not worked. This is the line I added to my nuxt.config:

```
serverMiddleware: [bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }), bodyParser.json(), '~/api'],
```

I am unsure if the content type is not set correctly or I am missing something simple here. I know I am able to use various libraries to grab the parameters from the url string which I have access to, as Axios is working as expected and adding my 'params' object onto the end of my get request. But a lot of solutions I have seen to other problems is 'oh its as simple as accessing req.query' Alas Express fails to define a req.query object, or even req.params or req.body.

Hopefully that is enough detail to go on, thanks a lot for reading and any suggestions.

Answer (score 7):

Well that's an unpleasant surprise to try to use the get request in Nuxt for the first time, isn't it? Nuxt creates a connect instance which leads to some pitfalls. It's req is the Node.js http request object, so **it doesn't have the `query property` and `request.body` is also being skipped in get requests!**

But there is a way for everything. Your code:

```
  axios.get('/api/getDailyFeedback', {
      params: {
        start: '2018-05-01'
      }
    })
```

Translates to the following URI call:

**/api/getDailyFeedback?start=2018-05-01**

So you've got all the params in the URI where you can retrieve them from via url parsing. Module `url` ships with Node.js by the way.

```
const url = require("url");

router.get('/getDailyFeedback', (req, res) => {
   let queryData = url.parse(req.url, true).query
   console.log('Query:', queryData.start)
});
```

I wrote a little helper that extends req with a custom property. Here's the code:

```
router.use((req, res, next) => {
  var theQuery = url.parse(req.url, true).query
  req.queryData = theQuery 
  next()
})
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
router.get('/getDailyFeedback', (req, res) => {
   console.log('Query:', req.queryData.start)
});
```

Other way to pass params via get is by using optional uri segments:

```
router.get('/getDailyFeedback/:start?', (req, res) => {
   console.log('Query:', req.params.start)
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution to this, I ended up doing something similar to get the right parameters. 

However it is fantastic to know the reason why I can not access the request value, thank you for taking the time to answer this despite the  age of the question.

Comment: You're welcome @Thermetro - I think that's always a good thing to understand a problem and share it with public - it save us all a little bit of headache ;)

Answer (score 2):

I am using Nuxt 2.15 and I can access the query parameter like this `req._parsedOriginalUrl.query`

Answer (score 0):

You can access Nuxt get params without additional modules.
Just use:

> req.request.get()

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else in the future

```js
const { Router } = require('express')

Router.get('/orders', async (req, res, next) => {
    const request = req.query.sometext;
    res.json({data: request});
});

module.exports = Router;
```

```html
<script>
    export default() {
        async mounted() {
            const orders = await axios.get(`/api/orders`, {
                params: {
                    sometext: 'bla bla'
                }
            });
       }
   }
</script>
```

http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req